Change the folder with python scripts under Windows
I’ve installed the latest version of python under Windows 10 to c:\python312. However, when I install some python modules via pip they appear not in this folder, but in %APPDATA%\Python\Python312. Is there any way to change this path to other folder? I want to have the whole python package in one folder in order to copy it to another PC or laptop.
I didn’t find any variable to set in order to change the location of python modules.

Make sure you have write access to the Python installation folder. Otherwise simply create an venv at the path of your choice and install the modules into it by activating the venv (execute venvpath\Scripts\activate.exe )

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sounds like you are looking for virtual environments. Then all you need to copy over is requirements.txt
